# Escape special characters with bcp in Sybase ASE

Tags: database, sybase, sap-ase, bcp

I am trying to use parallel bcp to copy multiple parts of a file to a table in Sybase ASE. However, there are a few fields that have special charaters and I want to escape them. 
Is there any way I can do that? I tried looking around but I couldn't really find an escape character in this case.

Comment: Are you running into issues?  You don't actually mention having any errors.  What does your BCP command look like? How was the source file created and how is it structured?  BCP isn't an interactive tool, so you can't just escape characters, but what you might be able to do is make a different choice when creating the source file that would avoid this issue.  Give details and background information when asking your questions.  It makes it easier for people to understand what the issue might be, and offer solutions instead in  a shorter amount of time. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Michael sorry about that. I think I figured out the problem though.